# Unable to properly scale image within container

Tags: css

I am having trouble scaling an image within a container.  I have two columns, the left column set at 280px and the right column taking whatever is left.  The image goes into the right column - we do not know its size beforehand (in the example it is 947px).

If the window is large enough all is fine, but when it becomes smaller the size of the image forces the right column under the left column.  The image finally scales to the body once the window becomes small enough.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <style type='text/css'>
    @media only screen and ( min-width: 641px ) { /* 641 or greater */
      img { max-width: 100%; height: auto; display: block; }
      .leftcol  { width: 280px; float: left; outline: 5px dotted green; } 
      .rightcol {               float: left; outline: 5px dotted red;   }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="leftcol">
    Home
  </div>
  <div class="rightcol">
    <img src="https://glsmyth.files.wordpress.com/2014/07/a-space-in-time.jpg" alt="Homepage image" />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to set `width: 100%` on the `img` as well. `max-width: 100%` is relative to the *img* native size. `width` is relative to the the containing element. `img { width: 100%; max-width: 100%; height: auto; display: block; }`

Comment: Just use `display: flex;` and the `flex` property https://codepen.io/MrFuze/pen/ExKmxpM

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox is a good solution for what you're trying to acheive. With the modifications below, it will work as intended.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type='text/css'>
        @media only screen and ( min-width: 641px) {
            body {
                display: flex;
                align-items: flex-start;
            }
            img {
                max-width: 100%;
            }
            .leftcol {
                width: 280px;
                min-width: 280px;
                outline: 5px dotted green;
            }
            .rightcol {
                outline: 5px dotted red;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="leftcol">
        Home
    </div>
    <div class="rightcol">
        <img src="https://glsmyth.files.wordpress.com/2014/07/a-space-in-time.jpg" alt="Homepage image" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

No more `float`s, `min-width` set on the `.leftcol` and only `max-width` on the image.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things going on:

1. `Float` doesn't calculate remaining space very well, so you can use `calc(100% - 280px)` on your right column. This ensures that it's always 100% MINUS the other column width:
2. Your image still needs `width: 100%` set, since `max-width` is relative to the image's actual size:

```css
@media only screen and ( min-width: 400px) {
  /* 641 or greater */
  img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .leftcol {
    width: 280px;
    float: left;
    outline: 5px dotted green;
  }
  .rightcol {
    float: left;
    outline: 5px dotted red;
    width: calc(100% - 280px)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="leftcol">
  Home
</div>
<div class="rightcol">
  <img src="https://glsmyth.files.wordpress.com/2014/07/a-space-in-time.jpg" alt="Homepage image" />
</div>
```

Using `flex` is better solution for you.

```css
@media only screen and ( min-width: 400px) {
  /* 641 or greater */
  .flex {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
  img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .leftcol {
    width: 280px;
    outline: 5px dotted green;
  }
  .rightcol {
    outline: 5px dotted red;
    flex: 1 1 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="leftcol">
    Home
  </div>
  <div class="rightcol">
    <img src="https://glsmyth.files.wordpress.com/2014/07/a-space-in-time.jpg" alt="Homepage image" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good information that works,  I appreciate the help.